# display triangle on left side of screen

Tags: html, css

I have the following div which aligns to the left side of the screen

css

```
#nav {
 position: fixed; 
 height: 50px; width: 50px;
 display: block;
 background-color: #000;
}
```

This div contains an icon acting as a link

html

```
<div id="nav">icon</div>
```

I want the div to be a triangle (pointing towards the right) and not a square

Comment: http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find this site useful: https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

**Right-facing triangle:**

```
#triangle-right {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 50px solid transparent;
    border-left: 100px solid red;
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
}
```

You can adjust the border properties to change the width, height, and color of the triangle.

Something like this is probably what you're looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/kh2xsoh2/1

**HTML**

```
<div id="nav"><span>icon</span></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#nav {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 25px solid transparent;
    border-left: 50px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
    position: fixed;
}

#nav span {
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 0;
  left: -45px;
  color: white;
}
```